# Best way to log access to web pages

Tags: erlang, cowboy, nitrogen

One of my website is using Nitrogen with a Cowboy server.
I would like to log every access to web pages just like Apache does with access.log.
What would be the best way to do that ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use cowboy middlewares https://ninenines.eu/docs/en/cowboy/1.0/guide/middlewares/

Just create a simple log module:

```
-module(app_web_log).
-behaviour(cowboy_middleware).

-export([execute/2]).

execute(Req, Env) ->
    {{Peer, _}, Req2} = cowboy_req:peer(Req),
    {Method, Req3} = cowboy_req:method(Req2),
    {Path, Req4} = cowboy_req:path(Req3),
    error_logger:info_msg("~p: [~p]: ~p ~p", [calendar:universal_time(), Peer, Method, Path]),
    {ok, Req4, Env}.
```

and add it in list of middlwares:

```
    {ok, _} = cowboy:start_http(http, 100, [{port, 8080}], [
            {env, [{dispatch, Dispatch}]},
            {middlewares, [cowboy_router, app_web_log, cowboy_handler]}]).
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using Nitrogen on top of the Yaws web server instead, since it performs access logging by default.

Comment: This is a solution but I would like to keep using CowBoy if possible.
I found that one way to log every request with cowboy is using [hooks](http://ninenines.eu/docs/en/cowboy/HEAD/guide/hooks/) but should I use a system to buffer the writing so I don't bottleneck with all the I/O generated by writing logs ?

Comment: The only way to be sure of that will be to measure your system. But in Yaws the default logging has a `gen_server` open a file for writing in raw mode, and logging calls cast to the `gen_server` process, which then writes it. BTW you'll also have to worry about log rotation.

Comment: I will look at Yaws source code to see how they do it.
Thank you for your indication.

Answer (score 1):

Each underlying webserver does it differently (or not at all) - this is something simple_bridge does not yet have abstracted.

So in the case of cowboy, you'll likely have to rig it up yourself.

If you're using a newer build of Nitrogen (if you have the file `site/src/nitrogen_main_handler.erl`), then you can edit that file to manually log yourself. For example, using erlang's error handler, you could add something simple like:

```
log_request() ->
    error_logger:info_msg("~p: [~p]: ~p", [{date(), time()}, wf:peer_ip(), wf:url()]).

run() ->
    handlers(),
    log_request(), %% <--- insert before wf_core:run()
    wf_core:run().
```

Then whatever happens with the log can be handled by configuring error_logger to write to disk (http://erldocs.com/17.0/kernel/error_logger.html?i=13&search=error_logger#logfile/1)

If you use an older Nitrogen (which would have `site/src/nitrogen_cowboy.erl`), then you would similarly edit that file, once again before the `wf_core:run()` call.

Alternatively, your hooks option with cowboy could work as well. I've not worked with them, so you're on your own there :)